# Align two circled divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align these two divs with no success. I want the black circle to be inside the white circle. How can I do that? Why the vertical-align: middle does not working? 
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

```css
    .discOuter {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 178px;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        width: 178px;
    }

    .discInner {
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 155px;
        width: 155px;
        margin: 19px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="discOuter">
        <div class="discInner"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` does not account on `block-level` (DIV) elements (unless you specify a different `display` property like `inline` or `inline-block`).

```css
.discOuter {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 178px;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        width: 178px;
    }

    .discInner {
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 155px;
        width: 155px;
        margin: 12px; /* fixed the issue */
        /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="discOuter">
        <div class="discInner"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. How did you arrive to 12px? you just guessed and tried it?

Comment: @user3355028 :) the little ferry in my pocket, you know ;) No problem! Glad I could help. Happy coding and all the best in 2015

Comment: @user3355028 P.S: `178 - 155 = 23` px margins, but we need half, so `23/2 = 11,5` so I've used **12px**. not perfect, I know, misses 1px. You rather set the inner circle width to `156px` so you can use the perfect 11px margin

Answer (score 1):

Try with `transform` css property

```
.discOuter {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 178px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    width: 178px;
    /**/
    position: relative;
}
.discInner {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: inherit;
    height: 155px;
    width: 155px;
    /**/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejnfgzx5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.discOuter` as `display: table-cell`:

**Snippet**:

```css
    .discOuter {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 178px;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        width: 178px;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .discInner {
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 155px;
        width: 155px;
        margin: 19px;
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="discOuter">
        <div class="discInner"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pseudo` element for giving border like in the below example

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3o1Ljces/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.discInner {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 19px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.discInner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="discInner"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or you can also use `-ve` `margin` for aligning the `div` supported for older version changed the width and height to even so that i can get half the value for subtracting the `margin`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ejnfgzx5/2/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.discOuter {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 178px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  width: 178px;
  position: relative;
}
.discInner {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: 156px;
  width: 156px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -78px 0 0 -78px;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="discOuter">
        <div class="discInner"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```